# Как реализовать таймер?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в питоне реализовать таймер обратного отчета ???

```
import time
def timer(t: int):
    for r in reversed(range(1, t + 1)):
        print(r, 'sec')
        time.sleep(1)
a = timer(10)
if a == None:
    print('Program is over')
elif a == 5:
    print('34r34')
```

Comment: Подробнее о возможных подводных камнях при использовании `time.sleep()` см. [Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import threading
import random
import time

def timer(t: int, result: list):
    def wait(c0=result.pop()):
        for r in reversed(range(1, t+1)):
            result.append(random.choice(range(4)))
            print('timer', r, result)

            if result[-1] == c0:
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(1)

    thr = threading.Thread(target=wait)
    thr.start()
    while thr.is_alive():
        yield result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    stop = 3
    result_ = [stop]
    # ждать 10 сек, пока в result_ не появится 3
    for a in timer(10, result_):
        print('ожидание', stop, a)
        # time.sleep(1)

    if 2 in result_:
        print('34r34')
    print('Program is over', result_)
```

out:

```
timer 10 [1]
ожидание 3 [1]
ожидание 3 [1]
timer 9 [1, 2]
ожидание 3 [1, 2]
timer 8 [1, 2, 1]
ожидание 3 [1, 2, 1]
timer 7 [1, 2, 1, 3]
34r34
Program is over [1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Чтобы оно заработало нужно импортировать какие то модули ???

Comment: только стандартный модуль `time`.

Comment: Простите, возможно я задам тупой вопрос, но как сделать так, чтобы таймер работал параллельно с прогpамой (пример в вопросе сверху)

Comment: в тред выноси его