# Перед завершением работы в 18:00 написать print("END")

Tags: python

Имеется скрипт который каждые 10 секунд делает скриншот

```
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import sched, time
import os

if not os.path.exists('./screen'):
    os.makedirs('./screen')

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc):
    dt = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img.save('./screen/' + dt +".png", "PNG")
    s.enter(10, 1, do_something, (sc,))

s.enter(10, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Возможно ли сделать условие, что бы перед завершением принудительно скрипта выводилось на экран `print("END")` ?

Под принудительно, я подразумевю какой-то цикл, который к примеру в 18:00 сам будет завершать работу моего скрипта и выводить на экран `print("END")`

Comment: А каким образом скрипт завершается принудительно? И вывод на экран подразумевает вывод в консоль, из которой до этого и вызывался скрипт?

Comment: Зависит что значит *"перед завершением принудительно"*. Если по Ctrl+C, то вокруг run() добавьте `try/except KeyboardInterrupt`. Можно ещё atexit модуль (только для нормального выхода или потестировать какие сигналы он понимает).

Comment: @jfs @mikkik Под принудительно, я подразумевал какой-то цикл, который к примеру в 18:00 сам будет завершать работу моего скрипта и выводить на экран `print("END")`

Comment: Так в чем проблема проверять время в процессе выполнения скрипта?

Comment: В чём вопрос? Как `s.enterabs()` вызвать? Как 18:00 в time.time значение превратить? Как выйти из скрипта в callback (работает ли `sys.exit()`).

Comment: @jfs вопрос в том, как выйти из этого бесконечного цикла в 18,00

Comment: И? Пробовали sys.exit() вызвать?

Comment: `dt = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M")` if dt > '18:00': sys.exit()  else: **код который я привел выше**?

Comment: `datetime.now().hour > 18`

Comment: @OuFinx чтобы вызвать код в указанное время, используйте s.enterabs(...)

Comment: @mkkik а как задать минуты? datetime.now().hour > 18:30 ?

Comment: @OuFinx, datetime.now().minute

Comment: @mkkik datetime.now().minute - это я понятно. Но как записать вместе `datetime.now().hour` и `datetime.now().minute` что бы получилось `datetime.now() > 18:30

Comment: Вариант с `strftime`, который вы написали, будет работать в связи с возможностью сравнения строк одинаковой длины по значению, но лучше так не делать, а явно сравнивать числа.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сохранять каждые 10 секунд снимок экрана в отдельный файл и выйти после 18:00 по локальному времени:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime as DT
import time
import pyscreenshot  # $ pip install pyscreenshot pillow

while DT.datetime.now().time() < DT.time(18, 0):  # < 18:00 obey local clock
    time.sleep(10 - time.time() % 10)  # sleep until the next 10 seconds boundary
    image = pyscreenshot.grab()
    filename = f'screenshot-{DT.datetime.utcnow():%Y%m%d%H%M%S}Z.png'
    image.save(filename)
    print(filename)        
print("END")
```

В именах файлов используется UTC время, так как локальное время может быть немонотонным.

См. [Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044)

---

Чтобы напечатать `END` и выйти из `s.run()` цикла в вашем коде сегодня в 18:00 часов по локальному времени, достаточно `s.enterabs(..)` вызвать перед `s.run()`:

```
import sys
from datetime import time as datetime_time

def do_exit():
    print("END")
    sys.exit()

end_time = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), datetime_time(18, 0))
s.enterabs(end_time.timestamp(), 2, do_exit)
```