# Проблема с зацикливанием функции, при помощи threading.Timer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from datetime import datetime
import threading
mydate = datetime.now() #сегодня
time_start=mydate.replace(day=mydate.day+1, hour=3, minute=4)#время запуска
def starter():#произвольная функция
    print('hello world')

delta_time=time_start-mydate#разница между запуском и сейчас
reload=delta_time.seconds+1 #эта же разница в секундах
s = threading.Timer(reload, starter)#запуск функции starter, через заданное количество секунд
s.start()
```

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: каким образом зациклить выполнение функции, так, чтобы она выполнялась(без перезапуска скрипта) один раз в день согласно таймеру?

Comment: Либо опишите явно в чём вы видите проблему с вашим кодом: что ожидали получить, что вместо этого происходит. Либо заголовок вопроса поменяйте на: "как выполнить функцию раз в день в указанное время без перезапуска скрипта". Явно укажите причины, почему "без перезапуска". Связанный вопрос: [Перед завершением работы в 18:00 написать print("END")](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616927/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы выполнять код каждый день в заданное время, проще и надёжней использовать средства операционной системы такие как cron или Windows task scheduler, чтобы запустить скрипт, который выполняет действие и выходит. В противном случае, приходится самостоятельно решать такие проблемы как:

- кто перезапустит скрипт, если он умрёт по любой причине (память закончилась, неожиданная ошибка) -- можно запускать скрипт как сервис (демон) из под systemd, supervisord, etc
- кто перезапустит скрипт, если он повиснет (процесс живой, но никаких действий не выполняет) -- может потребоваться сервис (watchdog), который слушает периодические сигналы (heartbeat) и перезапускает скрипт, если он перестал их посылать. В свою очередь, кто-то должен следить что сам watchdog сервис является работоспособным, итд.

Если забыть об этих проблемах, то функцию в заданное время можно [с помощью `sched.scheduler()` запускать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime as DT
import sched
import time

DAY = DT.timedelta(1)

def some_func(dt):
    print(dt) # do something
    dt += DAY
    s.enterabs(dt.timestamp(), 0, some_func, [dt]) # schedule the next time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time)
dt = DT.datetime.combine(DT.datetime.today(), DT.time(10, 0)) # today 10:00
s.enterabs(dt.timestamp(), 0, some_func, [dt])
s.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Timer

def starter():
    print('hello world')
    Timer(1, starter).start()

starter()
```