# Сопрограммы(корутины) на Python: как независимо друг от друга выдавать значения в консоль

Tags: c#, python, unity3d

Например, нужно независимо друг от друга выдавать значения в консоль. Сейчас работаю на *Unity* (C#) и там подобное реализовано довольно просто:

```
void Start() //Этот метод вызывается в начале
{
    StartCoroutine(Сor1);
    StartCoroutine(Сor2);
    StartCoroutine(Сor3);
}

IEnumerator Сor1{
    while (True)
    {
        Debug.Log("log cor 1")
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    }
}


IEnumerator Сor2{
    while (True)
    {
        Debug.Log("log cor 2")
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
    }
}

IEnumerator Сor3{
    while (True)
    {
        Debug.Log("log cor 3")
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(15);
    }
}

void Update(){ //Он вызывается каждый кадр
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.K)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }
}
```

Подобный код будет выдавать в консоль "log cor 1" каждую секунду,
"log cor 2" каждые 10 секунд и "log cor 3" каждые 15 секунд до тех пор, пока мы не нажмем "К" на клавиатуре или не выключим программу.

Как такой же функционал реализовать на питоне?

Comment: Изучайте Python, если вам нужно писать код на нем. можете отсюда начать https://www.python.org . Или вы хотите, чтобы его писали за вас?

Comment: @AndreiS. Благодарю за ужасно полезный совет) В официальных мануалах рассматриваются какие то отделенные от реальности случаи, а такого простого и конкретного решения нет. Вопрос элементарный, многим только начинающим изучать питон пригодится. 
Будет неплохо если будет подробный ответ

Comment: Вы что то пробовали и у вас что то конкретное не получилось или вы просто просите писать код за вас?

Comment: @tym32167 на самом деле зря минусы. ТС не просит написать за него, он лишь спросил есть ли аналог в питоне и если есть, то как называется и в какую сторону копать.

Comment: @AndreiS. аналогично ↑

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну, меня смутило, что ТС не пытался ничего, а сразу пришел с вопросом. Потому я и поставил минус.

Comment: @tym32167 не пытался ничего что? найти ответ на вопрос есть ли аналог? откуда ты знаешь пытался он или нет? если он даже не знает по каким параметрам искать и вообще есть ли аналогия, то по каким критериям он должен был попытаться сделать поиск? А писать какой-либо код никто не просил

Comment: @АлексейШиманский например, взять ключевые слова из заголовка своего вопроса и загуглить "coroutines python", найти доку и спрашивать, что оттуда не понятно. Откуда знаю, что не пытался? Так так вопрос поставлен.

Comment: @tym32167 если бы все умели правильно составлять поисковые запросы, то никто бы не приходил с вопросами на SO. И опять же, выпадки что с твоей что со стороны Анрея были цитирую "просто просите писать код за вас?". Никто не просил. Так что если имеется информация **Как такой же функционал реализовать на питоне?** то можно в общих чертах и сказать, показать что читать, куда копать, как это называется по правильному, что рассматривать, привести пример этой фичи никак не связывая его с предоставленным кодом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский разве нужен особый навык, чтобы заголовок собственного вопроса забить в гугл?  Следуя твоей логике, можно что угодно спрашивать, даже не пытаясь самому вникать, так как не все умеют пользоваться поиском в интернете. Да, я может был и резковат, я признаю, прошу у ТСа прощения. Но это не отменяет того факта, что, судя по вопросу, ТС не проводил никаких исследований до того, как вопрос задать. А если и проводил, то не написал об этом. И не считай это спором с тобой, я только пояснил, за что поставил минус-ведь это моё право, ставить минусы, и я считаю, что сделал это обоснованно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот coroutine, которая печатает периодически в консоль:

```py
import asyncio

async def print_periodically(period):
    while True:
        print(period)
        await asyncio.sleep(period)
```

См. [Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044)

Чтобы запустить три цикла с разными периодами:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()    
tasks = [print_periodically(period) for period in [1, 10, 15]]
try:
    print('Press Ctrl+C to exit')
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        task.cancel()
    loop.run_forever()  # allow the tasks to shutdown cleanly
finally:
    loop.close()
```

Скрипт выходит по <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>.

[Asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html#asyncio) это не единственный способ запускать coroutine в Питоне. Например, можно посмотреть [как `trio` библиотека это делает](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html).

Для создания переносимых интерактивных консольных программ таких как `ptpython`, [можно `prompt_toolkit` модуль использовать](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
from prompt_toolkit import prompt_async  # $ pip install prompt_toolkit
from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import Keys, Registry

async def interactive_prompt():
    registry = Registry()

    @registry.add_binding('K')
    @registry.add_binding(Keys.ControlC)
    def _(event):
        event.cli.set_return_value(False)

    await prompt_async('Press K to exit.', patch_stdout=True,  # show prompt
                       key_bindings_registry=registry)

coros = [print_periodically(period) for period in [1, 10, 15]]
background_task = asyncio.gather(*coros, return_exceptions=True)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(interactive_prompt())
background_task.cancel()
loop.run_until_complete(background_task)  # shutdown cleanly
loop.close()
```

Пример демонстрирует как только избранные задачи отменить.