# asyncio — Как одновременно ждать пользовательского ввода с консоли и читать сообщения с сервера

Tags: python, консоль, concurrency, asyncio

Искал библиотеку для отлова нажатия горячих клавиш. Нашел pyhk, но что то установить ее не выходит, она зависит от PyHook3, а после установки PyHook3, все равно не видит библиотеку и из-за этого отказывается устанавливаться. Помогите пожалуйста.
Может есть какая-то встроенная библиотека для этого не сложная в использовании?

PS: У меня консольная программа-клиент, которая одновременно ждет ввода пользователя и ждет сообщения от сервера. Нужно чтобы программа не пропускала данных с сервера из-за того, что ждет пользовательского ввода. То есть чтобы пользовательский ввод был неблокирующим. Такое возможно? Асинхронность обеспечивает asyncio.

`reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8887 , loop=loop)`

читаю с помощью

```
var = await reader.read(1024)
```

Comment: Как вы пытались установить эти библиотеки?

Comment: @jfs мне нужно отловить комбинацию клавиш (в общем то любую) пока мое окно активно.

Comment: @vladF pip install, python ......//setup.py install а ту которая pyhk просто копирую в каталог libs так как там только один файл

Comment: @Алексей какую GUI библиотеку используете?

Comment: @jfs пока никакую, в последствии сделаю через tkinter

Comment: Да для этого больше подойдет больше tkinter

Comment: а как там это сделать?

Comment: @Алексей то есть ваш вопрос: «как в tkinter выполнить действие по нажатию клавиши»?

Comment: @jfs как в консоли сделать действие по нажатию клавиши. У меня просто два процесса работают постоянно переключаясь. Один ждет ответа сервера, а второй ждет нажатия комбинации от пользователя.

Comment: @Алексей то есть у вас не GUI, а консольное приложение? В чём проблемы с input() функцией, чтобы ввод получить? В комментариях не нужно необходимую для ответа вопроса оставлять, обновите ваш вопрос. Нажмите [edit]

Comment: Небольшой пример использования не помешал бы. Пока больше тянет на комментарий.

Comment: @AK у меня есть программа клиент, которая одновременно должна проверять не пришло ли че с сервера и одновременно отлавливать, если пользователь хочет что то отправить на сервер(то есть ввести команду с клавиатуры) input блокирует процесс и не дает возможности переключаться между процессами. Может я делаю что то не так?

Comment: @jfs input блокирует процесс. То есть я тогда пропущу данных приходящие с сервера

Comment: @Алексей  вот [пример кода, где одновременно и ввода c консоли  ждут и выполняются другие корутины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712046/23044)

Comment: на Windows, особенно легко с консоли ввод асинхронно ждать: просто цикл c `while not msvcrt.kbhit(): await asyncio.sleep(.4)` а потом: `ch = msvcrt.getwch()`, чтобы символ с консоли прочитать.

Comment: @jfs но этот ввод не будет виден пользователю, так же? Хотя можно все флагами сделать.

Comment: @Алексей: можно скрыть, можно показать ввод. Как хотите. К примеру, `getpass.getpass()` пытается скрыть по умолчанию ввод (пароль), а `input()` показывает ввод.

Answer (score 0):

у вас убунта или винда? Если убунта, то в терминале пишете что-то типа

```
sudo apt-get install pip3
```

(этим вы устанавливаете установщик библиотек для питона) а затем

```
pip3 apt-get install tkinter.
```

Comment: у меня винда и pip стоит уже или нужен именно pip3?

Comment: pip3 насколько я знаю для питона 3 версии, если у вас 2 версия и винда, то я особо знаниями помочь не могу, просто в интернете вбейте tkinter скачать. По одной ссылке перейдите и скачайте. Сам я так не делал, и поэтому могу дать только приблизительные показания

Comment: у меня python3 а зачем нужен tkinter если у меня консольное приложение? он же вроде для окон придуман?

Comment: сразу бы сказали, для использования кнопок в ткинтере нужно создать окно