# не читаются данные с сервера asyncio

Tags: python, asyncio

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks= [loop.create_task(tcp_client(loop)), loop.create_task(reading_from_server()), loop.create_task(waiting_for_command())]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
loop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
loop.close()
```

В первой корутине создается соединение во второй ожидаются данные с сервера, в третьей ожидается ввод пользователя
Ввод пользователя не блокирующий и отлавливается

```
reader,writer = None, None
f = True
async def tcp_client(loop):
    global reader
    global writer
    global f
    print("tcp_client")
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8887 , loop=loop)

    '''login'''

    while True:
        nick = input("Nickname: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        data = {nick:password}
        writer.write(("login " + json.dumps(data)+'\n\n').encode())
        data = await reader.read(1024)
        data = data.decode()
        if data =="logon successful\n\n":
            print(data[:-2])
            f = False
            break
        else:
            print(data[:-2]+ " Try again")
```

в этой корутине ответ от сервера читается успешно, но в других корутинах, ответ почему то не читается.

```
async def reading_from_server():
    global f
    global reader
    global writer
    print("reading_from_server")
    while True:
        if f:
            await asyncio.sleep(2.0)
        else:
            break
    data = ""
    while True:
        print("here!!")
        data += await reader.read(1024)
        print(data)
        print("in reading from server")
```

В этой корутине почему-то ответ не читается. 
Сервер

```
class EchoServerClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
```

там же `connection_made` создает `self.transport` 
и сервер отправляет через `self.transport.write(("HELLLOOOOOO").encode())`
клиент второй корутиной не получает это сообщение

Создал новую корутину которая просто печатает все, что приходит на reader.read(1024) и ничего не пришло.
Сервер:

```
class EchoServerClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    storage = Storage()
    all_users = {}
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.login = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.storage.online.discard(self.login)
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
    def data_received(self, data):
        self.all_users[self.login]=self.transport
        data = data.decode()
        if data.startswith("login "):
            logon = json.loads(data[6:-2])
            self.login = list(logon.keys())[0]
            print(self.login + " connected")
            self.transport.write(self.storage.user_connection(logon).encode())
            self.storage.online.add(self.login)
        elif data.startswith("msg"):
            print("msg")
            l = json.loads(data[4:-2])

            """l[0] - who will get msg 
            l[1] - what message he gets"""
            self.storage.msgs.setdefault((self.login,l[0]), [])
            self.storage.msgs[(self.login, l[0])].append(("You", l[1]))
            self.storage.msgs.setdefault((l[0],self.login), [])
            self.storage.msgs[(l[0], self.login)].append((self.login, l[1]))
            self.all_users[l[0]] = (("msg "+ self.login + "\n\n").encode())

            """send notice to user that he has new message"""
            """wrong method of saving msgs!!! fix it !!! May be dict of pairs like (sender, reciever) = [(who, message), (who, message)]"""
        elif data.startswith("dialog"):
            self.transport.write(("HELLLOOOOOO").encode())
            print("dialog")
            data_ = data[7:-2]
            msgs = self.storage.get_messages(self.login, data_)
            print(msgs)
            self.transport.write((msgs + "\n").encode())
        elif data.startswith("online"):
            print("online")
            string = "online:"
            string += json.dumps(list(self.storage.online))
            string+="\n\n"
            print(string)
            self.transport.write(string.encode())
        elif data.startswith("offline"):
            print("offline")
            string = "offline:"
            string += json.dumps(list(self.storage.all - self.storage.online))
            string+="\n\n"
            print(string)
            self.transport.write(string.encode())





loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = loop.create_server(
    EchoServerClientProtocol,
    '127.0.0.1', 8887
)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
#try:
loop.run_forever()
#except KeyboardInterrupt:
 #   pass

server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Клиент:

```
async def tcp_client(loop):
    global reader
    global writer
    global f
    print("tcp_client")
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8887 , loop=loop)

    '''login'''

    while True:
        print("loging")
        nick = "vlad" #input("Nickname: ")
        password = "vlad" #input("Password: ")
        data = {nick:password}
        writer.write(("login " + json.dumps(data)+'\n\n').encode())
        print("logging.....")
        data = await reader.read(1024)
        print("logged")
        data = data.decode()
        if data =="logon successful\n\n":
            print(data[:-2])
            f = False
            break
        else:
            print(data[:-2]+ " Try again")


    '''2 Streams. One - reading from server. Second - waiting from combination to enter'''

async def reading_from_server():
    global f
    global reader
    global writer
    print("reading_from_server")
    while True:
        if f:
            await asyncio.sleep(2.0)
        else:
            break
    data = ""
    while True:
        print("here!!")
        data += await reader.read(1024)
        print(data)
        if not data.decode().endswith('\n\n'):
            continue
        """work with data"""
        decoded_data = data.decode()[:-2]
        if decoded_data.split()[0] == "msgs":
            """got msgs with someone"""
            msgs = json.loads(decoded_data[5:-2])
            for i in msgs.items():
                print(i[0], ': ', i[1])
            """use msgs"""
        if decoded_data.split()[0] == "msg":
            """"you've got new message from ...."""
            msg = """You've got new message from """ + decoded_data[4:-2]
            """use as label"""
            print(msg)
            """update dialog if msg was on it"""
            #if self.dialog == decoded_data[4:-2]:
             #   get_messages(self.dialog)
        if decoded_data.split()[0] == "online":
            """all online people, comms when someone join or go offline"""
            self.online = json.loads(decoded_data[7:-2])
            online = ""
            for i in self.online:
                online += " " + i
            print("online:" + online)
            """refresh the data!!!!"""
        if decoded_data.split()[0] == "offline":
            self.offline = json.loads(decoded_data[8:-2])
            offline = ""
            for i in self.offline:
                offline += " " + i
            print("offline:" + offline)
            """refresh the data!!!"""
        #await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
async def waiting_for_command():
    global f
    global reader
    global writer
    print("waiting_for_command")
    while True:
        if f:
            await asyncio.sleep(2.0)
        else:
            break

    while True:
        data = ""
        while True:
            while True:
                while not kbhit():
                    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
                c = getwch()
                print(c)
                if c=='\r':
                    print(data)
                    break
                data+=c
            break

        if data.startswith("msg"):
            whom = data.split()[1]
            msg = data[5+len(whom):]
            writer.write(("msg "+ json.dumps((whom,msg))+"\n\n").encode())
        if data.startswith("dialog"):
            writer.write((data+"\n\n").encode())
        if data=="online" or data == "offline":
            writer.write((data + "\n\n").encode())
        else:
            pass
        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)

async def listening():
    global reader
    while True:
        d = await reader.read(1024)
        print(d)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [listening()]
tasks+= [loop.create_task(tcp_client(loop)), loop.create_task(reading_from_server()), loop.create_task(waiting_for_command())]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
loop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
loop.close()
```

Comment: 1- если вы думаете, что проблема во вводе пользователя, то легко проверить, заменив `reading_from_server()` на [`print_periodically()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712046/23044) и наблюдая что вывод идёт 2- с другой стороны, если проблема с `reading_from_server()`, то наоборот заменив другие корутины на `print_periodically()`, можно убедиться, что это не починило сервер. То есть код ожидания ввода с клавиатуры никак не сможет помочь с ответом на вопрос "почему данные с сервера могут не читаться Попробуйте *минимальный*, но *полный* пример кода привести, который демонстрирует проблему [mcve]

Comment: в сторону: нет нужды `loop.create_task()` вызывать. `asyncio.wait()` самостоятельно обернёт ввод по необходимости.

Comment: @jfs Все равно не приходит ответ от сервера.

Comment: у вас input() вероятно блокирует поток в котором цикл событий исполняется поэтому ничего не происходит (можно убедиться если рекомендациям из предыдущего комментария последовать). Попробуйте любое вводное руководство по asyncio какое вам нравится пройти, чтобы не пытаться блокирующие функции в корутинах напрямую вызывать.

Comment: @jfs у меня отсутствует input ввод читаю с помощью  msvcrt.getwch()

Comment: поиск слова input по странице сделайте.

Comment: @jfs эти inputы выполняются до выхода из корутины и никак не мешают дальнейшему выполнению. Это единоразовая вещь для регистрации пользователя. Проблема во второй корутине. Она не принимает данные когда первая отработала до конца

Comment: попробуйте заменить вызовы input() на фиксированные значения и посмотрите что будет, чтобы точно знать.

Comment: @jfs ничего не изменилось. В программе нет ни одного inputa но все равно что то не дает другим корутинам читать данные от сервера.

Comment: попробуйте*минимальный* но полный пример кода в вопрос добавить. Словами опишите желаемое поведение и подробно по шагам что вместо этого происходит. Добавьте пример ввода вывода если необходимо.

Comment: @jfs добавил код

Comment: вы уверены, что нельзя сократить код?

Comment: @JFS сократить? я просто не могу понять почему reader не работает в других корутинах. Может и можно сократить....

Comment: @Алексей [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Кажется нашел ошибку. Проблема была в том, что читал я по 1024 байт соответственно один `reader.read(1024)` забирал все данные и другие корутины не получали всех данных. Читая через `reader.readuntill(separator= b"\n\n")` читается как и задумано.