# Как в Python использовать await c input

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio

Я тут немного застрял с наверняка простой вещью. Коротко о проблеме:
- Подключён asyncio
- Созданы 2 async корутины user_io и task_manager
- В user_io() есть input, который напрочь игнорируется await
- task_manager() выполняется только после завершения user_io()
Внимание вопрос - Как сделать ожидание ввода и другие корутины "параллельными"?
Спасибо за помощь!

```
# Ждёт пользовательский ввод
async def user_io():
    try:
        # Ждём действия от пользователя
        while True:
            # Await, который ниже не работает!
            command = await input('Введите команду (С to EXIT): ')
            if re.match(r'[cC]', command):
                break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Скрипт остановлен по комбинации клавиш')

# Корутина, выполняемая параллельно с ожиданием пользовательского ввода
async def task_manager():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("I'm a task manager 1!")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("I'm a task manager 2!")


if __name__=="__main__":
    # Запускаем цикл событий
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [
        loop.create_task(user_io()),
        loop.create_task(task_manager())
    ]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: [пример асинхронного ожидания ввода, используя prompt_toolkit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/712046/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`input()` - это блокирующаяся функция. Вызов блокирующихся функций в асинхронном коде блокирует цикл событий. Поэтому их надо запускать в отдельном потоке. Да и прерывание от клавиатуры вы так в асинхронном коде не поймаете. По-хорошему для этого надо назначать обработчик вызовом метода [add_signal_handler()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.add_signal_handler), но в Windows это не работает.

```
import asyncio
import signal

def shutdown():
    # Отменяем все задачи, кроме вызвавшей
    for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
        if task is not asyncio.tasks.Task.current_task():
            task.cancel()


async def user_io():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Ждём действия от пользователя
    while True:
        # Запускаем input() в отдельном потоке и ждём его завершения
        command = await loop.run_in_executor(None, input, 'Для выхода введите C:\n')
        if command.lower() == 'c':
            shutdown() # Отменяем все задачи
            break      # и выходим из цикла


# Сопрограмма, выполняемая параллельно с ожиданием пользовательского ввода
async def task_manager():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            break # Выходим из цикла, если задачу отменили
        counter += 1
        print("I'm a task manager {}!".format(counter))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Устанавливаем обработчик Ctrl+C
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda n, f: shutdown())

    # Запускаем цикл событий
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # Задача ждущая завершения сопрограм user_io и task_manager
    main_task = asyncio.wait([user_io(), task_manager()])
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        # Позволяем main_task завершиться
        loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
    loop.close()
```

Comment: как то все трудно. Почему бы уже не юзать настоящие потоки?

Comment: @AndrioSkur во-первых, конкретно в Python получить выгоду от использования потоков ещё труднее из-за GIL. Во-вторых, потоки потребляют существенно больше ресурсов, чем цикл событий. В-третьих, писать стабильный многопоточный код намного труднее. Там ждут гонки, взаимоблокировки, нарушения инвариантов и прочая боль. Наконец, как сказал Алан Кокс, потоковое программирование нужно тем, кто не умеет программировать конечные автоматы :)

Comment: 1- ваш код и так потоки использует (default executor) 2- при ожидании  ввода GIL обычно автоматически отпускается 3- пару слов о ситуациях, в которых подобные хаки при завершении работы полезны, можно привести для будущих читателей

Comment: 1 - Использует, но только как дверку в синхронный мир. Иногда без этого не обойтись. К счастью, редко. 3 - Вы про отмену тасков и повторный вызов `run_until_complete`? Просто один из способов остановить задачи находящиеся в бесконечном цикле и завершить работу цикла событий так, чтобы он не ругался на необработанные исключения и незавершённые футуры.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Огромное спасибо! Это решение мне подошло.

Answer (score 1):

`input` блокирует поток до ввода (как и все функции без await). Есть библиотека `aioconsole`, где это организованно на более низком уровне, что позволяет не фризить весь поток, а использовать await - вот так:

```
from aioconsole import ainput

async def some_coroutine():
    line = await ainput(">>> ")
    ...
```