# Ожидание ввода пользователя

Tags: python-3.x

Как сделать так, чтобы программа проверяла ввод пользователя в консоль в произвольное время?
То есть, чтобы она не "ждала" ввода чего-либо, а продолжала работать

Comment: Вызывать `input` в отдельном потоке или сопрограмме.

Comment: А можно подробнее?)

Comment: Не видя ваш код, сложно понять какие именно подробности вам нужны. Может [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/788495/204271) пригодится.

Comment: Спасибо большое!