# python asyncio input

Tags: python, asyncio

Почему в python asyncio нет неблокирующего input?

Например я жду данные отпользователя, а скрипт в это время читает запускает браузер.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в Python использовать await c input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/788430/204271)

Comment: помоему плохой ответ. там все также блокируется.

Comment: Но результат это не меняет. У asyncio нет неблокирующего input. Я надеялся, что меня разубедят

Comment: @ДавидШико на Виндовс нельзя асинхронно работать с терминалом, а на линуксе проще форкнуть синхронную читалку терминала