# Динамическая проверка строк в txt и запуск/остановка потоков по строкам

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Есть рабочий скрипт, который запускает поток с функцией на каждую строку загруженного txt:

```
def work():
   while True:
        requests.get(line)
        time.sleep(11)

for line in base:
    threading.Thread(target=work,args=(line)).start()
```

вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы например каждую минуту строки в base.txt проверялись повторно, и если одну строку удалили- ее поток завершался, а если добавили- то стартовал новый поток с этой строкой?
В base.txt содержатся адреса сайтов, с новой строки каждый, например:

```
mysite.com
yoursite.com
```

В фунцкии work бесконечным циклом к этим сайтам идет запрос и проверка определенной информации

Comment: Расскажите подробнее про файл `base.txt`. Что за строки и как они используются в функции `work`? При повторном запуске как можно определить какая строка к какому потоку относится? Функция `work` работает пока ее не остановят или сама может завершиться?

Comment: @suit поправил вопрос

Comment: А как line используется в потоке? Из приведённого кода складывается ощущение, что вообще никак.

Comment: @Александр поправил вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Попытка убить потоки снаружи указывает на ошибку в дизайне программы. Потоки следует останавливать (если это вообще оправданно), только с кооперацией с их стороны. Это не случайность, что нет [`Thread.stop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)метода, в отличии от к примеру [`Process.terminate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate).

Чтобы периодически выполнять функцию в отдельных потоках и запускать/останавливать выполнение отдельных циклов повторения раз в минуту   в соответствии с текущим содержимым входного файла, [можно `call_repeatedly()` использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22498708/4279) и простой [временно́й цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044):

```
import time

stop_calls_to = {}  # hostname -> cancel future calls
while True:
     with open('base.txt') as file:
         hostnames = set(filter(None, map(str.strip, file)))

     # stop calls to hostnames that are not in base.txt
     for hostname in (stop_calls_to.keys() - hostnames):
         stop_calls_to[hostname]()
         del stop_calls_to[hostname]

     # add new repeating calls from base.txt
     for hostname in (hostnames - stop_calls_to.keys()):
         stop_calls_to[hostname] = call_repeatedly(11, check_site, hostname)

     time.sleep(60)  # wait a minute until the next sync
```

[`watchdog`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) позволяет следить за файлом, чтобы без долгой паузы новые изменения отслеживать.

При большом количестве сайтов, лучше асинхронные вызовы использовать (к примеру, с помощью [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#getting-started))  вместо создания отдельного потока для каждого сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Наверно как-то так:

```
while True:
    # Открываем файл и делаем список из строк
    with open('base.txt') as f:
        base = f.readlines()

    # Проверяем каждую строку на наличие потока с таким же именем
    # Если потока нет, то стартуем его
    for line in base:
        if line not in current_threads:
            current_threads.append(line)
            threading.Thread(target=work, name=line).start()

    # Проверяем есть ли в списке запущенных потоков такие, которых нет
    # в файле. Если есть лишние, то удаляем их из списка активных потоков.
    new_thred_list = []
    for thread in current_threads:
        if thread in base:
            new_thred_list.append(thread)
    current_threads = new_thred_list

    sleep(60)
```

В функцию `work` добавляем проверку на актуальность данного потока

```
if threading.current_thread().name not in current_threads:
    break
```

`break` разорвет цикл `while` в функции `work`, тем самым завершит соответствующий поток

Comment: 1- не стоит [удалять элементы из списка, по которому обход идёт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044) 2- `args=(line)` это ошибка.

Comment: 2. это у автора скопировал, не суть. 1. вообще, не вижу ничего криминального, если бы итерировал черз индекс, может есть риски

Comment: В вопросе код может вообще хоть SyntaxError содержать. В ответе должен быть рабочий код, если явно не указано обратное.

Comment: @jfs, удалил, чтобы вас не смущать :)

Comment: @jfs, добавил `break`. Так вроде бы проблем не должно быть

Comment: мне никаких одолжений не нужно делать. `args=(line)` следовало на `args=[line]` заменить. Сравните: `Thread(target=print, args=('abc')).start()` и `Thread(target=print, args=['abc']).start()`.¶ Не ясно, что вы с помощью `break` хотите получить. Не вижу где вы останавливаете предыдущие проверки, которых уже нет в `base.txt`.