# Отсрочить время выполнения функции

Tags: python, циклы, время

У меня  есть две функции

```
def func1()
def func2()
```

Мне нужно отметить время выполнения первой функции, прибавить к нему, например, 15 секунд и запустить вторую. Первая функция выполняется по условию, а условие для второй - +15 сек к первой. Функции зациклены для дальнейших повторов, но это понятно, вопрос, как время отметить.

Простое написание time.sleep(15) ко второму циклу с второй функцией недостаточно.

Comment: Т.е. вы сделали у первой функции sleep, и не хотите дожидаться его окончания, а сразу перейти ко второй функции? Что-то странное вы хотите, распишите подробнее для чего это

Comment: что значит "недостаточно"? Чем конкретно полученное поведение от желаемого отличается? В чём проблема с `func1(); sleep(15); func2()` или `Timer(15, func2).start(), func1()` (среди многих других вариантов) в зависимости от того что конкретно вы ожидаете. См. [Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос –

```
from time import time, sleep
while True:
    start = time()
    func1()
    sleep((time() - start) + 15)
    func2()
```