# Поочередная замена строк в одном txt файле из другого python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два txt файла: в файле 1.txt строку №5 нужно менять поочередно строками из файла 2.txt, где 10 строк с интервалом в 60 секунд. То есть каждую минуту в файле 1.txt содержимое строки №5 должно меняться на содержимое новой строки из 2.txt до окончания там строк.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как заменить строчку в .txt файле через python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/654183/23044)

Comment: попробуйте по шагам задачу решать, если на каком-то шаге застрянете, то задайте вопрос именно об этом шаге: №1 читайте 2.txt по строчно (если не знаете как спросите)¶ №2 замените 5-ую строчку в 1.txt на найденную строчку (см. ссылку выше как строки по условию заменять). Чтобы найти 5-ую строчку можно использовать `for n, line in enumerate(file, start=1): if n == 5: replace`¶ №3 подождите минуту ([Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044)) и повторите с шага №1 (пока есть строчки в 2.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На 2-м, напишите комментарий, если не работает подправим.

```
import time
with open(r'2.txt', 'r') as f2:
    for line in f2.readlines():
        with open(r'1.txt', 'r') as f1r:
            lines = f1r.readlines()
            lines[4] = line
        with open(r'1.txt', 'w') as f1w:
            f1w.writelines(lines)
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: С этим разобрался, спасибо, работает вроде корректно. А если усложнить немного задачу и после каждой замены строки еще открывать abc.exe из текущей папки, а потом только пауза 60 секунд и новый цикл с новой строкой?

Comment: перед `time.sleep(60)`импортируйте модуль os `import os` и запустите приложение `os.system('C:\Windows\system32\SnippingTool.exe')`

Comment: Приложение запускается, но при этом цикл с заменой строки и новым открытием приложения через 60 сек не повторяется снова

Comment: для цикла, можно не использовать `readlines()`, который весь файл сразу в память загружает. Вместо этого достаточно только одну строчку в памяти держать: `for line in file:` (а не `for line in file.readlines():`). Это не усложняет код, поэтому даже для маленьких входных файлов стоит более идиоматичный вариант использовать без явного вызова readlines() на for строчке¶ Вместо `os.system()`, которая всегда shell запускает, можно использовать `subprocess.check_call()`, чтобы запустить только саму команду, без `cmd.exe` и выбросить исключение, в случае ошибки (ненулевого кода возврата).

Comment: @AndreyJD если новая проблема возникла (цикл висит или ошибка произошла), то как отдельный StackOverflow вопрос задайте