# Python. Как организовать таймаут в While?

Tags: python, while, for

Всем салют. Имеется бесконечный цикл вида:

```
while True:
   #come code
```

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы он выполнялся `n` раз, после чего начинается минутная задержка, после которой цикл запускается снова. И так бесконечно выполняется `n` раз и ждет 60 секунд. Заранее спасибо.

p.s. была идея запихнуть в `while True:` что то типа `for i in range(n):`, после которого стоял бы `time.sleep(60)`, но решил тут узнать ...авось есть что проще.

Comment: *"авось есть что проще"*, а что сложного с `for i in range(n)` и `time.sleep(60)`?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: counter = 0

In [3]: while True:
   ...:     counter += 1
   ...:     if counter % 60 == 0:
   ...:         print(f'counter: {counter}, sleep.')
   ...:         time.sleep(60)
```

Но вариант с `for` мне кажется лучше.

Comment: лучше counter % n == 0, и n вынести в начало