# Необходимо чтобы в секунду цикл выполнялся не более 20 раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, время, sleep

Необходимо чтобы в одну секунду цикл выполнялся не более 20 раз.

Как можно этого добиться?

Comment: Зависит от точности, которая вам нужна: если достаточно обойтись sleep - то используйте его, если нужно точнее - то подсчитывайте число выполнений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `sleep()` приостанавливает выполнение для заданного количества секунд. Аргумент может быть числом с плавающей запятой, чтобы указать более точное время сна.

```
import time
for i in range(100):
    print(i, time.ctime())
    time.sleep(0.03)       # отрегулируйте интервал сна
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно выполнить 20 итераций одну за другой и подождать пока секунда закончится (если необходимо), а затем повторить сначала (псевдо-код):

```
from time import monotonic as timer

N = 20  # the number of iterations
INTERVAL = 1  # seconds

while True:
    start = timer()  # remember when the loop starts
    for _ in range(N):
        do_something()
    elapsed = timer() - start  # find out how long it takes
    if elapsed < INTERVAL:
       time.sleep(INTERVAL - elapsed)  # wait until the interval ends
```

Таким образом за секунду происходит не более 20 итераций и время в ожидании только по необходимости происходит.

Если хочется равномерно распределить каждую итерацию, чтобы каждая итерация начиналась бы на границе `INTERVAL / N` секунд (1/20 ~ 50 миллисекунд), то при условии, что `do_something()` занимает меньше 50 миллисекунд это легко сделать:

```
interval = INTERVAL / N
for _ in range(N):
    do_something()
    time.sleep(interval - timer() % interval)
```

Этот и другие варианты, которые для других случаев могут быть более подходящими, см. в [Как правильно сделать временный цикл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/577284/23044)

В случае, если исполнение идёт в нескольких потока/процессах, то можно использовать [семафор, который по времени ограничивает количество доступных токенов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33224087/4279):

```
from threading import Thread

def rate_limited_work(rate_limit=RatedSemaphore(N, INTERVAL)):
    while True:
        with rate_limit:
            do_something()

for _ in range(N):
    Thread(target=rate_limited_work).start()
```

Код выполняет одновременно `N` вызовов `rate_limited_work` функции, каждый в своём потоке. `rate_limit` семафор гарантирует, что не более `N` вызовов `do_something()` будут за `INTERVAL` секунд (не более 20 вызовов за секунду для данного вопроса).

Если работа в `do_something()` ограничена I/O или происходит в Си расширениях, которые GIL отпускают, то потоки могут эффективно ресурсы машины использовать в CPython.

Answer (score 0):

**time.clock()** - в Unix, возвращает текущее время. В Windows, возвращает время, прошедшее с момента первого вызова данной функции.(В миллисекундах)

В одной секунде тысяча миллисекунд.

```
import time

first_time = time.clock
all_time = 0
for i in range(1000000000000):
    all_time += time.clock()
    if all_time > 1000:
        break
    print(all_time)
```